# Count the number of rows in each column of a text file

Tags: text-processing, sed, awk

I have a text file with the following format:

5 3 1
2 3 4
.....
.....
i.e. space separated 3 columns of numbers/ However, some of the rows may be like:
2
3 1
So, I want to detect if the text file has any such inconsistencies and to print them out. How do I do this?

Comment: `awk 'NF!=3' < file.text`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[Stephane Chazelas suggested](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/93854/count-the-number-of-rows-in-each-column-of-a-text-file#comment142336_93854)

```
awk 'NF != 3'
```

This is a simple way of printing all the lines that don't have exactly three columns. If you also want the command to return a failure status if any such line is found:

```
awk 'NF != 3 {print; ++bad} END {exit(!!bad)}'
```

Remove `print;` to not print anything and only report the presence of such lines through the exit status.

You can also do this with grep:

```
grep -Ev '^[^ ]+ +[^ ]+ +[^ ]+$'
```

If you want to be more strict and print all the lines that don't consist of exactly three columns each containing an integer:

```
grep -Ev '^([0-9]+) +([0-9]+) +([0-9]+)$'
```

Use `[␉ ]+` instead of  `+` where `␉` is a tab character if you want to allow one or more tab as column separators. Use `(␉| +)` to allow either exactly one tab or a sequence of spaces.

Answer (score 1):

In case what you really want is what is asked in your question's title, this `awk` command will print the line number and number of fields in each line:

```
awk '{print NR,NF}'
```

Answer (score 0):

```
awk '{if(NF != 3) print NR,NF}' file.txt
```

This will print the row numbers in the file that do not have 3 fields and the number of fields they have.